# NFC sample Application for Nexus S Emulator

Tags: android, emulation, uniqueidentifier, nfc, smartcard

I'm  new to Android development. I am trying to Integrate NFC application on my Nexus S emulator which is installed in my windows machine. I am struggling a lot  to develop the application for NFC demo. Can anyone give me the idea  on how to crate the sample NFC  demo application. My intention is that I need to get some output during the smart card swiped over my Nexus s mobile and I should read the Unique id from that smart card I swipe. Can anyone please help me in developing the application for this. Can you send me the application for this  if you have.

Thanks in advance, 
Dilip.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.andevcon.com/AnDevCon_III/documents/AnDevConIII_Catalog.pdf)

> the Android emulator does not support NFC emulation

Also: There is some NFC example code [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/index.html).